# Export attribute data with GeoJSON in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, fields-attributes

I'm trying to create `.geojson` files that contain basic tracks and waypoints to be used in Leaflet.

I am able to export `.geojson` file from QGIS and display it on a Leaflet map. However, the exported files from QGIS have no attribute data to use in Leaflet.

Is there a way to export `.geojson` files that contain attribute data within the file?

Comment: Pkease provide some more context in your question. For example, what attributes you are expecting to see (perhaps include a sample of your data, or dummy data if your data are sensitive),  describe how you are exporting it, and show how the output GeoJSON looks.

Comment: OK, I will edit the question this evening. Thanks for the pointers @Matt :)